# $('div.img', this)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a very simple question, I am just learning jQuery plugins and saw this:

```
var nav = {};
nav.$ = $('div.nav', this);
```

Can someone please explain what this does? Why is the `$` there?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First $ is just a property name of `nav`, where as the second $ is jQuery object.

`$('div.nav', this)` is same as `jQuery('div.nav', this)`

So `nav.$ = jQuery('div.nav', this);`

To avoid confusion, you can use `nav.jqNav = jQuery('div.nav', this);`

Hope you can understand...

Refer [`http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/`](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

It is used purely as a property name. Nothing more. Just the same as using for example `nav.myProperty = something;`

In fact, the same as doing:

```
var nav = {
    $: $('div.nav', this)
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The $ is to show that it is a cached jQuery object (as opposed to the element).

Note that it is just a convention, there is no requirement to preface references to jQuery objects with a $.